# A classic image rebus

Tags: visual, rebus, movies

What classic movie line/catchphrase does this image represent?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> From the (now probably even more famous) "May the 4th be with you" we get the original line "May the force be with you." - Edit: The rebus itself gives "May, fours with you"

Comment: If you ignore the meme, there's also a large number of "fours" in the image ;)

Comment: Yes, that's what I was going for :)